# Why is the \$I_d\$ current in the saturation region unchanged?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

Once the electrons reach the end of the channel, they experience the high electric field in the depletion region surrounding the drain junction and are rapidly swept to the drain terminal. Therefore, the device still conducts, but I can't understand why the current is unchanged.

Comment: The current is unchanged -- compared to what? Other parts of the channel away from the end? Compared to a different mode of operation for the MOSFET? The current can't change at different parts of the channel because charge must be conserved.

Comment: Did you learn MOSFET's operation regions? @nanofarad. In reality, Id is still slightly increase, but in ideal it is unchanged. I just want to know why it is unchanged in physical.

Comment: I did learn them. I am asking clarification for your question because it was not worded clearly. Your comment does not help to clarify since it starts by stating that Id increases slightly (as a result of which effect that you care about?) but then asks why it's *un*changed in the physical case.

Comment: Okay, so why it is unchanged in physical case? @nanofarad

Comment: Again, unchanged compared to what base case? You've used the word "unchanged" multiple times, but you haven't stated what you're comparing it to. Compared to elsewhere in the channel? Compared to a different drain voltage? Compared to a different device geometry?

Comment: oh I've got it. I mean compared to drain voltage. when Vds increase, Id is unchanged. Can you explain this in physical case? @nanofarad

Comment: For a short-channel device, it does actually increase as the channel length is modulated. We take it into account with an output impedance term in parallel with the small-signal model's current source. I think the linked answer should cover your question, but if not, then please let us know with details about what further confusion you have.

Comment: If cars are on the highway and they get an open section and accelerate, but have to decelerate to the same speed, is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Example N-JFET: The width and the form of the depletion region is determined by VGS (general width) as well as VDS (unsymmetric form). The channel width becomes smaller in the drain region (equivalent to a broader depletion region).

- Small voltages VDS (max 1 V): The channel behaves (nearly) like an ohmic region because the influence of VDS on the form of the depletion region is not yet remarkable. Hence, ID increases (nearly) linearly with VDS.
- Rising VDS: The channel width becomes smaller close to the drain region and this effect counteracts (stops) the linear ID increase.
- Saturation region: Now the influence of the rising VDS dominates the width of the depletion region: Any further VDS increase causes the remaining n-channel to become smaller and smaller (pinch-off effect). As the result, both effects (ohmic behaviour and pinch-off) nearly cancel each other and ID remains nearly constant.
- As we know, in electronics nothing is ideal - and this applies, of course, also to the FET: Up to a certain extend, the ohmic behaviour of the channel cannot completely stopped by the pinch-off effect. Hence, there is still a small ID increase with rising VDS values.